# Show the content of a file by its name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to build a script that ask for user to type the name of the file, and once written, it simply shows what is inside this file, entirely.

---

**So for instance**,

Let's say I have a directory located in, **/home/evaluation/**, which contains severals files :

In /home/evaluation/**file01**,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

In /home/evaluation/**file02**,

```
Lorem ipsum sit amet.
```

In /home/evaluation/**file03**,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
```

---

I'm looking forward to build a script that will ask me to write, **the file name**, I want to read, and once this file written, it will show all its content.

So if I type : **file01**, it will show me :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Else, **if the file doesn't exist in the directory**, then it shall be written : "no file found".

Comment: Is there some reason you feel you need to loop over the directory?  Seems like you just want to cat the file if it exists or print a message if it does not.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are actually right, I don't need any loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if you get what you are looking for

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter file name  # ask for the file name
read fileName  # get the a file name from the user and store it in fileName
if [ ! -f $fileName ] ; then  # check to see if the file exists
   echo "File not found"  # print a message if it does not
   exit  # all done so exit 
fi
# cat the file if we are still here , ie the file exists
cat $fileName
```

`if []` in bash defines a *test* so
and `-f file_name` checks to see if the file exists and is a regular file
so  `[ ! -f $fileName ]` will be true if the file does not exist, so then the message will be printed, otherwise the contents will be printed

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was doing it wrong with a loop.